# Confused about Spark streaming application execution time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a simple Spark streaming WordCount application, which reads data from a Kafka topic. In this application, checkpoint is enabled to calculate accumulated word count. The stream internals is 1000ms. The following picture shows a table (delay, execution time, total delay, events) of micro-batches in this stream application. What makes me confused is that every 10 seconds, there is a micro-batch which takes around 4 seconds to execute, which is much more than the execution time of other micro-batches. Why does this situation occur? My application is just a very simple word count program.

[image]